# Android Copy and Rename from anywhere

Tags: android, file, rename

Trying to use the following code to copy a file from one directory to another and rename

```
String Path3= "/storage/extSDCard/DCIM/Camera/fred.jpg";
                File to = new     File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Barr.jpg"); 
                File oldFile = new File (Path3);
                oldFile.renameTo(to);
```

It doesn't appear to copy the file. in this case the path Path3 is on the SDCard but I also need it to copy from one directory to another on the device as well

Basically I'm using the gallery picker to pick an image from somewhere I convert the uri to a path I then need to copy the file from where it is stored to the pictures directory and rename it

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it from A variety of sources was going about it in the wrong way. This Code Works:

```
File sourceLocation = new File (Path2);
File targetLocation = new File (Path3 + "/" + imageFileName);
              Log.v(TAG, "sourceLocation: " + sourceLocation);
              Log.v(TAG, "targetLocation: " + targetLocation);
              try {
                  int actionChoice = 2;
                  if(actionChoice==1){
                      if(sourceLocation.renameTo(targetLocation)){
                          Log.v(TAG, "Move file successful.");
                      }else{
                          Log.v(TAG, "Move file failed.");
                      }
                  }
                  else{                           
                      if(sourceLocation.exists()){
                          InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
                          OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);
                          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                          int len;
                          while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                              out.write(buf, 0, len);
                          }
                          in.close();
                          out.close();
                          Log.v(TAG, "Copy file successful.");
                      }else{
                          Log.v(TAG, "Copy file failed. Source file missing.");
                      }
                  }
              } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
```